# Calculate the minimum and maximum in cvInRangeS

Tags: opencv

```
 cvCvtColor(frame, hsv_frame, CV_BGR2HSV);
 cvInRangeS(hsv_frame, hsv_min, hsv_max, thresholded);
```

I try to follow blue ball. To determine the maximum and minimum I open a picture I took with the camera, open it MS paint and doubles at (180/240) result out of me in H
And (255/240) the result of S and L
then i recive the next values:

```
108 113 115 112 105 H
145 40  107 129 143 S
97  129 96  102 124 L
```

So I chose the next values:

```
CvScalar hsv_min = cvScalar( 105, 40, 96 );
CvScalar hsv_max = cvScalar( 115, 140, 130);
```

But when I try to follow it hardly ever see him
Am I wrong calculation? or what can i do to improve the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all why do you convert your image to `HSV` and then talk about `HSL`? If I'm not mistaken they are different color spaces.

To determinate blue color using `HSV` color space use this range:

```
Min (H/S/V):  90,  50,  50
Max (H/S/V): 130, 255, 255
```

Also [this online converter](http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx) should help you.

And don't forget that `Hue` value after converting image to HSV using `CV_BGR2HSV` code is in range **[0..180]**, while using `CV_BGR2HSV_FULL` will give you range **[0..360]**.

Comment: CV_BGR2HSV_FULL gives you H value in range [0..255] not [0..360]