# Unable to convert YUV threshold limits to HSV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, hsv

I want to convert the yuv_min and yuv_max values to hsv_min and hsv_max. My code is as follows

```
yuv_thresh = [97, 43, 148, 188, 81, 167] // [y_min, u_min, v_min, y_max, u_max, v_max]

cv::Mat rgb_min;
cv::Mat hsv_min;
cv::Mat yuv_min(1,1,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(yuv_thresh[0],yuv_thresh[1],yuv_thresh[2]));

cvtColor(yuv_min, rgb_min, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR);
cvtColor(rgb_min,rgb_min,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
cvtColor(rgb_min, hsv_min, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::Vec3b hsv_min_vec = hsv_min.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  cout<< "hsv_min: "<< i << " = " <<(float)hsv_min_vec.val[i] << endl;
}

cv::Mat rgb_max;
cv::Mat hsv_max;
cv::Mat yuv_max(1,1,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(yuv_thresh[3],yuv_thresh[4],yuv_thresh[5]));

cvtColor(yuv_max, rgb_max, cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR);
cvtColor(rgb_max,rgb_max,cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
cvtColor(rgb_max, hsv_max, CV_BGR2HSV);
cv::Vec3b hsv_max_vec = hsv_max.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  cout<< "hsv_max: "<< i << " = " <<(float)hsv_max_vec.val[i] << endl;
}
```

The output I get is

> hsv_min: 0 = 30
>
> hsv_min: 1 = 255
>
> hsv_min: 2 = 120
>
> hsv_max: 0 = 20
>
> hsv_max: 1 = 154
>
> hsv_max: 2 = 232

It can be seen that hsv_min[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057490/wrong-conversion-from-yuv-to-bgr-using-color-yuv2bgr-in-opencv) > hsv_max[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057490/wrong-conversion-from-yuv-to-bgr-using-color-yuv2bgr-in-opencv).

Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Note: If in case anyone is thinking that why am I converting converting BGR2RGB in line 9 and and line 23, please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057490/wrong-conversion-from-yuv-to-bgr-using-color-yuv2bgr-in-opencv)

Comment: You are converting BGR values to RGB values but then you use BGR2HSV instead of RGB2HSV.

Comment: You have a 2 step algorithm. Have you verified the middle step (YUV -> BGR) before posting?

Comment: @m3h0w yes I have verified the middle step the BGR range is correct. Is there a direct way of converting YUV to HSV?

Comment: @AxelB. Please check the link that I have mentioned at the end. Due to the bug in opencv 2.4 im converting BGR2RGB actually to get BGR value.

Comment: i'm not sure this is your problem but try adding `_FULL` to the `cvtColor` colorspace parameter, like `BGR2HSV_FULL`. it's almost not documented at all but it gives you different result. look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504272/calculate-the-minimum-and-maximum-in-cvinranges) for example.